# mod expires in .htaccess = 500 Internal Error

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I tried many times but it still doesn't work:

When I add these following mod expires lines I get a 500 internal error but if I remove them everything works fine :

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive on
ExpiresDefault "access plus 30 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 15 days"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 months"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 months"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 months"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 months"
ExpiresByType text/js "access plus 1 months"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 months"
</IfModule>
```

I did `sudo a2enmod expires` and `sudo a2enmod header` and they are both enabled...

Any explanation? I've heard it can be something wrong in my `httpd.conf` but I don't have that file. I use **apache2 on Ubuntu 14.04**

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked your configuration on my test web server (Debian 6.0/Apache2) and it seems to be working fine.

Please check your error log (/var/log/apache2/error.log) and your configuration file (/etc/apache2/apache2.conf).

EDIT: After examining the log files it is clear that override option is not enabled completely in apache2.conf file (https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxU1M.jpg), thus causing the error when parsing .htaccess file.

Suggested to make the following changes:

```
<Directory /var/www>
    ...
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. What should I see/edit in apache2.conf? I'm a total newbie

Comment: First check the ErrorLog to make sure the error log is created. Then please find and attach the error log to the question.

Comment: Here's a screenshot of my apache2.conf and error.log files: http://imgur.com/a/vMB2k

Comment: Please change AllowOverride option value to "All" for Directory "/var/www" and restart the server. That will solve the issue.

Comment: Thank you so much Samvel, it works now! Couldn't have figured it out myself.